# How to make a webpage different based on whether or not someone has visited other parts of the site?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm rather new to html/css and almost know nothing too big on javascript so I'm not sure where to start on this. (And forgive me if I have improper use of terms!)
I basically am working on a piece of hypertext fiction that is told entirely through html/css and the user will be directed to read through it based on the locations in a town. There is a webpage called places.html which has hyperlinks to:

- sheriff.html
- saloon.html
- stables.html
- clocktower.html
- bank.html
- store.html

However, there is one more webpage I want to add, but I only want it to appear after the user has visited at least three of those webpages listed above. The new addition that would be able to be seen would be graveyard.html, but again, this is only after the user has gone through at least three of the other webpages.
I tried to find an answer to this and it seems as if cookies may be the solution? However, I only found one that changes what the index/first page appears to the user, so I don't understand it and searching on google doesn't seem to help me figure out a solution.
Hopefully this explanation is enough and I would appreciate any help I can get!

Comment: Your use-case sound a little bit strange to me. Most websites have some kind of server session management. However maybe using `localStorage` is enough for your use-case.

Comment: If you did it as a single page instead of multiple separate static sources, it would be pretty easy to simply store a count in regular JavaScript.

Comment: Without learning some JavaScript concepts, I think you'll find it challenging to be able to do more than copy + paste content from any answers here. That aside, a practical approach would be to run JS on every page which stores a unique identifier for each "location" in local storage when visited. It would also parse, validate, and count those identifiers on the "places" page to determine whether or not the "graveyard" link should be visible. [Here's an example of that](https://tsplay.dev/w1adAw) which you could load in a module script (`<script type="module">`).

Comment: What is a user in this context? One usage instance of one particular browser on one device? If so, local storage may be your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't really enough information to give a working example.

Add an `id` and `style` to your graveyard link, so you can easily access it with JS and hide it until you need it.

```
<a href="graveyard.html" id="hiddenlink" style="display:none;">Graveyard</a>
```

Each page should also contain the following code, it adds the page name to a list stored in localStorage, and when more than 3 pages are in that list the graveyard link is displayed.

When the graveyard page is visited, it resets the list and will be hidden again. (optional)

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    let page = window.location.pathname.split('/').pop()
    let list = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("list") || "[]")
    if (!list.includes(page)) { 
        list.push(page)
        localStorage.setItem("list", JSON.stringify(list))
    }
    if (list.length > 3) {
        document.getElementById("hiddenlink").style.display="block"
    }
    if (page == "graveyard.html") {
        localStorage.setItem("list", "[]")
    }
})
```